# IdentityServer4 AddSigningCredentials with Certificate

Tags: c#, certificate, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, signing

I have an SSL certificate installed on my domain and I wanted to use it for signing with IdentityServer 4. Now I found that there is a method which would let me do that:

```
services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredentials(certificate);
```

However, I cannot figure out how to actually get my certificate and pass it to the identity server.

I have tried the following:

```
var cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(fileName);
services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredentials(certificate);
```

The error that I get is it cannot convert from

> 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate' to 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SIgningCredential'

Now I don't understand why it is complaining about signing credentials when one of the overrides for the method is the certificate.

Comment: Use the overload that takes a `SIgningCredential` and create that by passing in the certificate.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto could you post an example?

Comment: I don't have VS right now, but it would be similar to `var cert = ...; var creds = new SigningCredential(cert); ...AddSigninCredentials(creds);`. Notice that you should be using `X509Certificate2`, `X509Certificate` has been deprecated for quite some time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up resolving it like this. I'm using a shared server where I am hosting this and I could not find the file name for the certificate or the path to get it. So I ended up just opening the store and finding it that way. Not very efficient, but it will do the trick until I move it to a dedicated server and have more control.

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2 cert = null;

foreach (X509Certificate2 certificate in store.Certificates)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(certificate?.SubjectName?.Name) && certificate.SubjectName.Name.StartsWith("CN=*.mysite.com"))
    {
        cert = certificate;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can't convert due to issue in permissions or loading the certificate as a stream.

In my case using IdentityServer3 the below code works:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Load the certificate that sign the Id or Jw token
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        string baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        return new X509Certificate2(
        Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ConfigMngr.GetAppSettingsValue<string>("IdSrv:SigningCertificatePath")), ConfigMngr.GetAppSettingsValue<string>("IdSrv:SigningCertificatePassword"));
    }
```

Then in owin's startup file, I am passing it as below:

```
  SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
```

I know in Idsrv4 it's a different implementation than the code I posted but it should be the same abstraction, for example, you loading X509Certificate but it's deprecated so make sure to use the correct overloading to load the certificate as stream and make sure to return the correct type.

Also, This code is testable with IdSrv4:

```
var fileName = Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "FileName" );            

    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("No Signing Certificate!");
    }

    var cert = new X509Certificate2(fileName, "Pass" );

    services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredential(cert)
```

So instead of using

```
X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(fileName);
```

You can construct a new X509Certificate2 certificate like this:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(fileName, "Pass" );
```

And pass it to the owin middleware:

```
services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredential(cert)
```

Comment: The libraries that IDS3 use and IDS4 use are completely different, as they don't even share the same ASP.NET version (4.x vs Core). I don't know why you assume an IDS3 example is useful

Comment: I know for sure, but they still use the same overloading for loading the X509Certificate2 which not even depends on the .Net version even it's core or not

Comment: @Marzouk no inner exception as this is compilation error

Comment: The SigningCredential is considered a better approach as it works as a far superior abstraction with helper methods to build almost any kind of key that .NET supports